# Many distorted frames when using rtsp stream from IP camera with opencv in python

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer, rtsp

I'm trying to track objects (Yolov5+DeepSort) by processing data received from an IP camera. To get video data I use OpenCV and RTSP protocol to connect to the camera.

The problem is that some of the received frames are heavily distorted, which automatically makes it impossible to correctly track objects on the video.

If I receive an RTSP stream through VLC, then there are no such problems. What could be the problem? Could this be due to a weak wifi signal from the router, or is it related to OpenCV. Maybe I should not work with live video, but process video from the archive. In this case, I do not know how to access the archive of video materials on the MicroSD card located inside the IP camera without having to constantly pull it out to download the archive

```
OpenCV 4.6.0
Python 3.8

python3.8 -c "import cv2; print(cv2.getBuildInformation())"

Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      avcodec:                   YES (58.134.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.76.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.70.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.9.100)
      avresample:                NO
    GStreamer:                   NO
    v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)
```

My code is:

```
import cv2
from cv2 import (VideoCapture, namedWindow, imshow, waitKey, destroyWindow, imwrite)
import os
os.environ["OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS"] = "rtsp_transport;udp"

video = VideoCapture("rtsp://admin:qwerty10@192.168.8.238:554/onvif1")
k = 0
while True:
    k += 1
    ret, frame = video.read()    
    # cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.imwrite('test'+str(k)+'.jpg', frame)            
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here are examples of distorted and normal frames I get:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Please tell me if I chose the wrong way to solve this problem

Comment: that is dropped packets. your system is under too much load. reproduce with gstreamer standalone... I highly doubt this has much to do with OpenCV. writing individual frames, especially PNG-compressed, to file will cost a lot of cpu time. do not do that for a live video.